# Returning current user on a website with Windows Authentication in IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, iis-7, windows-authentication

Using IIS 7.5, what IIS settings, web.config settings and C# code are needed to return the current windows user?

Web.config values are

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

ApplicationConfig values are

```
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
                <providers>
                    <add value="Negotiate" />
                    <add value="NTLM" />
                </providers>
            </windowsAuthentication>
```

Don't seem to do the trick.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Are you presented a username/password box when you visit? Is `User.Identity.Name` not what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set **Windows Authentication** to **Enabled** in your Visual Studio project's properties. In the project file (*.csproj*), this translates to:

```
<IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>enabled</IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
```

Also, set the **Managed Pipeline Mode** project property to **Classic**:

```
<IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>true</IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>
```